# Intellij project between Windows and Linux - use the 'default system provided' JDK?

Tags: intellij-idea, cross-platform, java

I've got two dev workstations, one running Windows, the other running Linux. I work on a Java project using Intellij on both. Both platforms have the Oracle JDK 7 installed in the default locations.

For some annoying reason, every time I switch platforms, I need to update the project configuration to specify what JDK it should be using. In the project's "Project SDK" setting, there's a JDK selection which includes two entries - 1 for a JDK in `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk_1.7` and the other for a JDK in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-jdk/`. If I open the project on Linux, I have to specifically set the Project JDK to be the second. If I save the project, close, commit, and then checkout and open on Windows, it complains it can't find the JDK, and I have to manually set it to the Windows version.

Why can't Intellij figure this out automatically? I appreciate that testing against multiple installed JDKs is a useful feature, but is there a way to tell a project to 'just use the default JDK'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your JDK configurations to have the same name, lile `1.6` or `1.7`. Project file references JDK by its name only so it will work out of the box in all IDEA installations on different operation systems, the only requirement is that there is JSDK defined under exactly the same name.